# Can a boundary event ever be of type "throwing"? Or how do you know from where it catches?

Tags: modeling, diagrams, process, bpmn

Just to provide context:
I am modeling a ticket (service management) process and specific actions are allowed in specific life cycle stages, so not in a straight sequence flow.

Therefore I encapsulated the respective task in a subprocess that now has several boundary events.

E.g. adding notes to the ticket. That can be done by two parties. So now I have two boundary events, catching and throwing (from a process perspective), but the icons are both catching, as one is catching via the message flow from another pool, the other catches from inside.

1. Is that correct? (I never saw a genuinely solid/filled throwing boundary event anywhere.)
2. How can I know (graphically) from where an event catches, generally? When I see a boundary event, it might catch from somewhere outside (at least when from another pool I should see a message flow I guess), or from inside the subprocess.
3. (Implicit assumption, that you cannot bypass the boundary event, meaning communication with tasks/processes in the subprocess must not happen directly w/o taking the step via a boundary event!?)

Happy to learn secrets.

*diagram obviously reduced :)*

[image]

Comment: I've looked at this a few times and I can't make sense of what you are asking here.  It's not clear what you mean by 'throwing' and 'catching', for example.  I would usually associate those terms with exception handling but I get the sense you are using them to mean something else.

Comment: Sorry for confusion. - I mean events that are sending and receiving a message.

Comment: @JimmyJames: Those terms have strictly defined semantics in BPMN. See section 10.5, paragraph 3.

Comment: @JörgWMittag Thanks. After looking at that page, I'm reminded of why I haven't found BPMN compelling.

Comment: @JörgWMittag Let me try to clarify:
The core is:

(a) I want to receive message events that are processed within the subprocess but are non-interrupting. So I understand that I must hava a sequence flow also then that goes back to the subprocess?
(b) I want to send messages out of the subprocess, also non-interrupting.

The concrete situation is that the process is waiting for a participant's action, that event will terminate it. But meanwhile messages may or may not be exchanged (repeatedly).

Comment: @MaK please use edits to clarify not comments. I suspect a good question is hiding here but I can’t see it yet.